# Python c[i] = int(n1[i]) + int(n2[i]) + d TypeError: 'reversed' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python

Мне нужно реализовать алгоритм сложения длинных чисел на Python. Тут совсем новичок и не понимаю некоторых особенностей. Я получаю ошибку:

```
c[i] = int(n1[i]) + int(n2[i]) + d
TypeError: 'reversed' object is not subscriptable
```

Почему к перевернутой строке нельзя обращаться по индексу?
Сам код:

```
number1 = input('Введите первое длинное число = ')
number2 = input('Введите второе длинное число = ')
l = max(len(number1), len(number2))
n1 = reversed(number1)
n2 = reversed(number2)
d = 0
c = ''
for i in range(0, l, 1):
    c[i] = int(n1[i]) + int(n2[i]) + d
    if c[i] > 9:
        c[i]-=10
        d = 1
    else:
        d = 0
print(reversed(c))
```

Новый код:

```
def rev(line):
    line = list(line)
    l = len(line) - 1
    for i in range(0, l // 2, 1):
        tmp = line[i]
        line[i] = line[l - i]
        line[l - i] = tmp
    s = ''.join(line)
    return s


number1 = input('Введите первое длинное число = ')
number2 = input('Введите второе длинное число = ')
l = max(len(number1), len(number2))
number1 = rev(number1)
number2 = rev(number2)
if len(number2) < l:
    while len(number2) != l:
        number2+='0'
print(number1)
print(number2)
d = 0
c = ''
for i in range(l):
    s = 0
    s = int(number1[i]) + int(number2[i]) + d
    if s > 9:
        s -= 10
        d = 1
    else:
        d = 0
    c += str(s)  # 3
if d > 0:  # 4
    c += str(d)
print(c[::-1])
```

Comment: В данном случае у вас не строка, а объект класса `reserved`. Попробуйте `str(reserved(number1))` и `str(reserved(number2))`.

Comment: Целые числа в Python и так сами по себе могут быть условно бесконечной длины, нет необходимости реализовывать это самостоятельно

Comment: `reversed(number1)` -> `''.join(reversed(number1))`. Или `reversed(number1)` -> `number1[::-1]`.

Comment: @АнонимныйПаша, ваше предложение не работает.

Comment: @andreymal, некоторый смысл в этом есть. Если числа из сотен тысяч цифр, код выше будет быстрее чем стандартный Питон `print(int(input()) + int(input()))`.

Comment: @andreymal алгоритм должен под любой язык идти, не ток под Python, вот в чем суть

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `reversed` не переворачивает строку. Он только возвращает специальный объект с помощью которого символы строки можно перебрать в обратном направлении. Перевернуть строку можно так: `number1[::-1]`.
2. Если строки разной длины будет обращение за пределы короткой строки. Их нужно подравнять.
3. Строку `c` лучше заменить на список. Быстрее будет работать.
4. Забыт последний перенос. Например `50 + 50`-> `00`.

Всё остальное работает как нужно:

```
number1 = input('Введите первое длинное число = ')
number2 = input('Введите второе длинное число = ')
l = max(len(number1), len(number2))
n1 = number1[::-1] + '0' * (l - len(number1))    # 1 и 2
n2 = number2[::-1] + '0' * (l - len(number2))
d = 0
c = []                                           # 3
for i in range(l):
    s = int(n1[i]) + int(n2[i]) + d
    if s > 9:
        s -= 10
        d = 1
    else:
        d = 0
    c.append(s)                                  # 3
if d > 0:                                        # 4
    c.append(d)
print(''.join(map(str, reversed(c))))            # 3
```

**P.S.** Более питоновский код. Вместо переворота строк они итерируются задом-наперед:

```
import itertools


number1 = input('Введите первое длинное число = ')
number2 = input('Введите второе длинное число = ')

carry = 0
c = []
for d1, d2 in itertools.zip_longest(
    reversed(number1),
    reversed(number2),
    fillvalue='0'
):
    carry, d = divmod(int(d1) + int(d2) + carry, 10)
    c.append(d)
if carry > 0:
    c.append(carry)

print(''.join(map(str, reversed(c))))
```

Comment: Cписок нельзя создавать, изменяется пространственная сложность алгоритма :С

Comment: Со строкой `c` пространственная сложность такая же. Она линейная в любом случае.

Comment: Спасибо, без списка попробовал так

Comment: ```
for i in range(l):
    s = 0
    s = int(number1[i]) + int(number2[i]) + d
    if s > 9:
        s -= 10
        d = 1
    else:
        d = 0
    c = c.join(str(s))  # 3
if d > 0:  # 4
    c = c.join(str(d))
print(c)
```
Но все равно ошибка(код не форматировался в комменте :С)

Comment: Просили при реализации не использовать список вообще, работать только со строкой(

Comment: Строки в Питоне неизменяемые - нельзя написать `c[i] = str(s)`. Вы можете сделать так: `с += str(s)`. Это даст нужный результат. Но есть одно но - этот вариант очень медленный если числа действительно длинные (10000 знаков).

Comment: Да, уже сделал так. Но окончательно запутался в алгоритме. Если брать l = max и одно число длиннее другого, просто будет ошибка о несуществующем индексе(когда например первое из 4 символов, второе из 3 и при попытке number2[3] - 4го элемента). Если брать min, то до него просто не доходит очередь. Нулями дополнять тоже говорили нельзя :С. Спасибо вам в любом случае большое, много исправил с ваших подсказок

Comment: Добавил в описание новый код, с добавлением нулей, учел добавление переноса, как вы и говорили, но 50+50 почему-то выводит 00, а не 100 все равно (

Comment: `rev` ничего не переворачивает. Или уберите его (чем плохо `[::-1]`?), или исправьте.